# What x belongs to if not all $x_i$ belong to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: vectors

We know if all $x_i$ belong to $\mathbb R$, then we can say $x$ belongs to $\mathbb R^n$. But if $x_n$ does not belong to $\mathbb R$, then what can we say about $x$?

$x= \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Then $x \notin \mathbb R^n$.  You'll have to add a bit more context if you have a more specific answer, or if you meant something different that what you asked...or provide more information about what, exactly, $x_n$ belongs to if it is not a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $x_n\in X$  where $X$ is any set. Then we can say $x\in \mathbb R^{n-1}\times X$ if it can help in the context you are working in.